# How can I create a not-equally-spaced sequence of numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, numbers, sequences

I want to create a not-equally-spaced sequence of numbers in MATLAB starting from 24 and ending to 511.The Sequence uses 32 and 33 alternately as the increment. Thus, the sequence would be as below : [24 56 89 121 154 186 219 251 284 316 349 381 414 446 479 511] Notice that :

```
    24+32=56
    56+33=89
    89+32=121
    121+33=154
```

...
I just wonder how to modify my own codes or to write new codes to have the answer. My own codes are below:

```
    t_3233=0;

    for k=24:(32+t_3233):511

        t_3233
        k

        if t_3233==1 
            t_3233=0;
        else if t_3233==0
            t_3233=1;
            end
        end

    end
```

Comment: You can combine two vectors to one: `sort([24:65:511, 56:65:511])`

Comment: Yes, it works out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case you can use:

```
len    = 16;
vector = round(linspace(24,511,len))
```